# my data us not displaying in textboxes from database

Tags: vb.net

This is the code I've tried. This code is on my test form and it works, but now in my final system it doesn't work despite their being the same   .

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Products where Barcode like '" & Barcodetxt.Text & "'", myConnection)
Dim userFound As Boolean = False
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

If (dr.Read() = True) Then
    While dr.Read
        userFound = True
        prdct = dr("Product")
        prc = dr("Price")
        brcddb = dr("BarCode")
        dscrtn = dr("description")
    End While

    TextBox1.Text = prc
    Barcodetxt.Text = ""
    ProducttxtBE.Text = prdct
    Subtotaltxt.Text = prc
    DescriptionBE.Text = dscrtn
    pricetxtBE.Text = prc
    BarcodetxtBE.Text = brcddb
    Quantitytxt.Text = 1
    Timer1.Enabled = False
```

Comment: my data is not displaying if i put this code "If (dr.Read() = True)"

Comment: Why are you using `like` in that SQL rather than `=`? Are you using wildcards? I doubt it with a barcode. Don't use `LIKE` unless you are specifically trying to find partial matches using wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `Read`, you advance to the next record. If you have already read the last record and you call `Read` again, you go past that last record and, therefore, have no data.  How many records are you retrieving?  Presumably one.  How many times does that mean that you need to call `Read`?  Once.  How many times are you calling `Read`?  Twice.  See the problem?

You need to get it together and learn how to use the `Read` method and the `HasRows` property.  Here are some scenarios and how you should use those members:

1. You are retrieving zero or one row and you want to do something different in each case.  In this scenario, you would call `Read` and catch the result.  Do as required if it is `False`, i.e. there are no rows, and use the data if it is `True`, e.g.

```vb
If reader.Read() Then
    myTextBox.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Column1"))
Else
    MessageBox.Show("No results")
End If
```

2. You are retrieving zero or more rows and you don't need to do anything special if there are no rows.  In this scenario, you would call `Read` in a loop and use each record as you read it, e.g.

```vb
While reader.Read()
    'Use current record here.
End While
```

3. You are retrieving zero or more rows and you want to do something specific if there no rows. In this scenario, you would use `HasRows` to determine whether there are rows or not, do as required if there are none and then call `Read` in a loop if there are are rows, e.g.

```vb
If reader.HasRows Then
    While reader.Read()
        'Use current record here.
    End While
Else
    MessageBox.Show("No results")
End If
```

It's not completely clear what your general scenario is but you need to determine whether to call `Read` and, if so, how many times, and also whether to test `HasRows`.  As a rule though, you need to actually use the current record immediately after EVERY `Read` call.  If you ever call `Read` twice without using data in between, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.